# jquery - execute when button is visible

Tags: jquery

In Wordpress my content is displayed as well with a PopUp. I want to have the following behaviour:

If a popup appears and the backbutton is pressed than the popup should be closed, i.e. the action from the Close button should be executed. Searching here I found the following approach:

```
 window.onload = function () {
    history.pushState("jibberish", null, null);
    window.onpopstate = function () {
        if ($("span.close").is(":visible")) {
            $("span.close").click();
        // Handle the back (or forward) buttons here
        // Will NOT handle refresh, use onbeforeunload for this.
            history.pushState('newjibberish', null, null);
            console.log('returned');
        } else {
            console.log('nothing to do???')
        }
 };
```

This works quite OK for the back button. What I couldn't figure out with this approach:

1. If no popup is present -> the back button itself should be exectued, i.e. back in the history of the browser.
2. Somehow this is a global function. Is it possible to load it ONLY when the `span.close` is visible? And unload when it is hidden? With this approach it would solve the previous question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, by manually going to your initial state you previously set (`"jibberish"`), then go back again manually (using `-1`):

```
var closeButton = $("span.close");    
window.onload = function () {
    history.pushState("jibberish", null, null);
    window.onpopstate = function () {
        if (closeButton.is(":visible")) {
            closeButton.click();
        // Handle the back (or forward) buttons here
        // Will NOT handle refresh, use onbeforeunload for this.
            history.pushState('newjibberish', null, null);
            console.log('returned');
        } else {
            console.log('manually going back to previous');
            history.go("jibberish");
            history.go(-1);
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Thx - this works in principle exactly the way as I was expecting. This solves exactly my first answer. Since it works - although my second q isn't answered - I'll accept it.

Comment: Yes, I actually seen no real advantage for the point 2, it would have been more complicated to achieve for the same result, and would still need to manipulate history because of first pushed inital state. The point 2 would be if you need to have 2 different behaviours for `onpopstate` in the same page